# Global error handling doesn't work in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, error-handling

I want to handle all unexpected errors in a WPF application. When I look at, there are different events for different situation to capture and control error. Also I added these in application constructor method

```
public App()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += OnFirstChanceException;
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
    Dispatcher.UnhandledException += OnDispatcherUnhandledException;
    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += OnUnobservedTaskException;
}
```

However, I try that for checking handling but they didn't work. What is the reason?

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //2021112242
{
    throw new StackOverflowException();
}
```

Comment: `App.xaml.cs` has an event you can subscribe to called `DispatcherUnhandledException.`

Comment: One note about it though, if you have any exceptions thrown on separate threads, they will not get caught natively.

Answer (score 1):

Every exception event has his own callback method & event object

```
// Dispatcher.UnhandledException
     private static void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
            {

            }
// TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException
            private static void OnTaskSchedulerUnobservedTaskException(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
            {

            }
//  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException    
            private static void OnCurrentDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
            {

            }

// AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException
    private static void OnCurrentDomainUnhandledException(object sender, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)
                {

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

`App` has an event for this called `DispatcherUnhandledException`.  This works in most cases but when the exception is thrown from a separate thread it gets a little hairy.

```
public partial class App
{
    public App()
    {
        // Globally handle errors/exceptions for a friendly close.
        DispatcherUnhandledException += DispatcherOnUnhandledException;
    }

    private void DispatcherOnUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.Exception.Display("An unhandled exception occurred, the application will now close.");
            e.Exception.Log(); // log the problem.

            Shutdown(-1); // assume not recoverable.
        }
        catch
        {
            Shutdown(-1);
        }
    }
}
```